# Spotify API with basic core PHP

Tags: php, spotify

I just need to show my own music on my website. So mine is not an "app" which other users will use. I simply want a PHP script that queries Spotify from time to time, perhaps once every day, and finds if there's a new song added to my playlist. If so, it adds that to my website and shows it on my site.

For this I'd like a very simple script that allows me to authenticate myself in a server side code (which will be executed via cron) and bring back all the tracks in a specific playlist. I'd prefer *not* to use any library etc, just plain PHP code.

But I'm not sure which '[Authorization API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)' here I should use. Curl is just for testing, yes? Not for actual code especially with GET as that would be insecure? Would appreciate any pointer to any code sample for this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried any of the api? And do you get and error maybe? IMHO spotify api is as straight as most apis out there. And you could do curl on php just like on shell anyways. So "just for testing" is not really true.

Comment: Doing it the CURL way would be the easiest way, but there's something in the URL that's more transient, like the code. Yes? I have the client ID and the Secret ID, but I shouldn't be passing those via the URLs anyway, yes?

Comment: clientID and Secret will still be seen on GET request traffic. But if what worried you is on the script, it could be leveraged on environment variable and concated as string.